# C# SQL Security

Tags: c#, sql, security

I currently have a large C# Winforms application that connects to a SQL database in the local network and uses this regularly throughout the application. I am currently using standard SQLConnections to connect and perform SQL queries.

Security is not my strong point and I have been alerted to the fact that these queries can be seen in plain text using a packet sniffer and are apparently susceptible to man in the middle attacks and also SQL Injection.

I am currently in the process of converting to EntityFramework which I believe would stop the risk of SQL Injection. Will Entity commands still be visible as plain text over the network and if so, what methods should I be using to mitigate the security risks?

Comment: Why don't you look for Stored Procedures!

Comment: I do use Stored Procedures but not for everything. It seems like it would be hard to maintain and test if I was to use SP for everything throughout the application.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations here a some suggestions to minimize security risks

Comment: Looking at this, it looks like if I was to use Entity with SSL encryption that should be enough to address the issues I mentioned?